# How to identify a form field type in php

Tags: php, forms

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="My name">
    <textarea name="about_me" id="about_me"></textarea>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />

    <select name="level">
        <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
        <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="Expert">Expert </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I have form like this,

My form fields are dynamically added.
After submitted the form, i need to identify the field type, needs to know as name is textbox value, about_me is textarea input, gender is radio option, level is dropdown etc..

is that any way to find out form field type in php.

Comment: append name attribute with identifier to identify the element like `name="textfield_name"`

Comment: You only get the name sent through the GET not the type. You would need to prefix your names or something like MyWay says.

Comment: @MyWay i thought the way you suggested only as of now, but needs to know is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: The simplest approach would be MyWay's. As an alternative you could come up with hidden input fields reflecting the name and type (e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="about_me:textarea">` or `<input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="gender:radio">`). However, this seems a bit like an overkill. Why do you need the type in the first place?

Comment: or you can assign a number as prefix, instead of big words, then match number with the control type say 1 -> textfield, 2 -> textarea,... and so `name="1_name"` much simpler!

Answer (score 2):

First: take MyWay's approach. It is straight-forward and dead simple. However, if you want to build up a more complex structure, you could use the following code. It sets up hidden fields as an array and holds the name and type, separated by a `:`:

**HTML Page:**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">

    <input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="name:text">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="about_me:textarea">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="gender:radio">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[]" value="level:select">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="My name">
    <textarea name="about_me" id="about_me"></textarea>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />

    <select name="level">
        <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
        <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="Expert">Expert </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Afterwards, in your PHP file:**

```
$fields = $_POST["fields"];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    list($name, $type) = explode(':', $field);
    $val = (!empty($_POST[$name]))?$_POST[$name]:"";
    if ($type == "textarea") {
        // do sth. useful with it
        // the value is in $val (if there's one)
    }
}
```